Does the concavity of a curve flip when a graph is reciprocated?
Been looking at functions such as $x^3-x+2$ and $\dfrac{1}{x^3-x+2}$ on Desmos and this certainly seems like a valid conclusion. However from my algebra, I can't seem to figure out why. It is definitely easy to prove why the derivative changes signs when reciprocated though.
$\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\dfrac{1}{g(x)}\\
f'(x)&=\dfrac{g'(x)}{g(x)^2}\\
f''(x)&=\dfrac{-g''(x)g(x)+2g'(x)}{g(x)^3}?\\
\end{align*}$

This would be true for the inverse function. Are you sure you don't mix the two concepts (inverse vs. reciprocal)  ?
See here

if we define flip as reciprocal of a function, then it's not necessarily to flip convex to concave. For example $f(x) = e^x$, both $e^x, e^{-x}$ are convex.
If we define flip as $-f(x)$, then that's correct.
